# Is Swift accessible if OpenStack is installed

Tags: linux, unix, openstack, openstack-swift, devstack

If I have OpenStack installed on my local(virtual) machine does it mean that I can access Swift form other external hosts using API?
I use DevStack install package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DevStack install, then you'll not be able to access OpenStack from outside with standard methods. 
You should try to use [SAIO](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html) which provides API and tools (curl, swift) to work with OpenStack Swift.